# save data into two tables at the same time using laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a Many to Many relationShip, I added a intermidiate table.

So I have the following models :

Model : Casting

```
class Casting extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
   
     protected $fillable = ["id_casting",
        "nom", "prenom" , "cine" , "date_naissance","lieu_naissance" ,"mineur","id_representant","id_type_facturation","artiste","fonction","id_type_casting ","tel1","tel2","email","photo","qualification","adresse","ville","pays","id_filiale","actif"
    ];
 
 protected $primaryKey = 'id_casting';
}
```

Model: Projet

```
class Projet extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

     protected $fillable = ["id_projet",
        "numero_projet", "id_client" , "id_agence_conseil","id_agence_production","id_agence_casting","description","date_tournage","date_premiere_diffusion","id_filiale","id_createur","actif"
    ];
     protected $primaryKey = 'id_projet';
}
```

Model: Projet_Casting

```
class Projet_Casting extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ["id_projet_casting", "id_projet","id_casting","id_contrat",
       "actif"
    ];
 
 /* protected $guarded = [];*/
 protected $primaryKey = 'id_projet_casting';

 protected $table = 'projets_castings';
}
```

Now I'm tryinh to insert in the same time data into table Projet and table Projet_Casting

So I'm using the following Controller :

```
$projets = new Projet();
         $projets->numero_projet = $request['numero_projet'];
         $projets->id_client = $request['id_client'];
         $projets->id_agence_conseil = $request['id_agence_conseil'];
         $projets->id_agence_production = $request['id_agence_production'];
         $projets->id_agence_casting = $request['id_agence_casting'];
         $projets->description = $request['description'];
         $projets->date_tournage = $date;
         $projets->date_premiere_diffusion = $datee_diffusion;
         $projets->id_filiale = Auth::user()->id_filiale;
         $projets->id_createur = Auth::user()->id;
         $projets->save();
   
         $projets_castings = new Projet_Casting();
         $projets_castings->id_projet = $projets->id;
         $projets_casting->id_casting = $request['id_casting'];
         $projets_casting->id_contrat = $request['id_modele_contrat'];
         $projets_casting->save();
```

But I get the following error :

```
message: "Creating default object from empty value"
```

in this line :

```
$projets_castings->id_projet = $projets->id;
```

When I checked the table Projet I found that data is inserted but in table Projet_Casting data is not inserted

Please help

Comment: first check `dd($projets->id)` value.

Comment: I get null , but why in database table is not null it is an auto incement value

Comment: It seems that your problem is not inserting data into multiple tables at the same time, but a specific error.